Inequalities about $x^n + b_1 x^{n-1} + b_2 x^{n-2} + \dots + b_n$, in which $n$ is an integer $> 2$ and $x$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $\dots$, $b_n$ are real

Let $n$ be an integer greater than $2$. Let $x$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $\dots$, $b_n$ be real numbers.
Define $f(x)$ to be $x^n + b_1 x^{n-1} + b_2 x^{n-2} + \dots + b_n$.
Prove or disprove the following propositions:
(1) if $|x| > 1$, and $|x + b_1| > |b_2| + \dots + |b_n|$, then $f(x) \neq 0$;
(2) if $x > 1$, and $x + b_1 > |b_2| + \dots + |b_n|$, then $f(x) > 0$;
(3) if $|x + b_1| > 1$, and $|x| > |b_n|$, and $|x| > 1 + |b_k|$ for every integer $k$ with $1 < k < n$, then $f(x) \neq 0$;
(4) if $x + b_1 > 1$, and $x > |b_n|$, and $x > 1 + |b_k|$ for every integer $k$ with $1 < k < n$, then $f(x) > 0$.

I suspect that all the four propositions are true.
I can prove the first two:
(1) If $|x| > 1$, and $|x + b_1| > |b_2| + \dots + |b_n|$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    |f(x)|
    \geq {} & |x^n + b_1 x^{n-1}| - |b_2 x^{n-2} + \dots + b_n| \\
    \geq {} & |x|^{n-1} |x + b_1|
    - (|b_2| |x|^{n-2} + \dots + |b_n|) \\
    > {} & |x|^{n-1} (|b_2| + \dots + |b_n|)
    - (|b_2| |x|^{n-2} + \dots + |b_n|) \\
    = {} & |b_2| (|x|^{n-1} - |x|^{n-2})
    + \dots + |b_n| (|x|^{n-1} - 1) \\
    \geq {} & 0,
\end{aligned}
$$
from which one concludes that $f(x) \neq 0$.
(2) If $x > 1$, and $x + b_1 > |b_2| + \dots + |b_n|$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x)
    \geq {} & x^n + b_1 x^{n-1} - |b_2 x^{n-2} + \dots + b_n| \\
    \geq {} & x^{n-1} (x + b_1)
    - (|b_2| x^{n-2} + \dots + |b_n|) \\
    > {} & x^{n-1} (|b_2| + \dots + |b_n|)
    - (|b_2| x^{n-2} + \dots + |b_n|) \\
    = {} & |b_2| (x^{n-1} - x^{n-2})
    + \dots + |b_n| (x^{n-1} - 1) \\
    \geq {} & 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
However, I do not know how to prove the last two yet.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.
